# Convert Drupal error message to JavaScript alert

Tags: status-messages

How I am able to do that?

I'd like to show the status/error messages in form of an alert using JavaScript instead of showing it on the screen.

Comment: Try this module http://drupal.org/project/better_messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think the [better messages module](http://drupal.org/project/better_messages) is for you.